# django-login-required middleware giving type error

Tags: python, django, middleware

In my django project I am trying to use the `django-login-required-middleware`. Upon running the server, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError at /

'bool' object is not callable
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/krishnan/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/krishnan/anaconda3/envs/django_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/login_required/middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    is_authenticated = request.user.is_authenticated()

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: 'bool' object is not callable
```

When I go to line 26 of the file `site_packages/login_required/middleware.py`, I see the following code:

```
# Django v2 now has request.user.is_authenticated as a boolean instead
#       of a function that returns a boolean
if django.VERSION[0] == 2:
    is_authenticated = request.user.is_authenticated
else:
    is_authenticated = request.user.is_authenticated()
```

I am using Django 3.1.6. I installed the middleware on 04 June 2021 with pip as instructed in the pypi page, and I presume it is the latest version(the `middleware.py` file does not show version info). As per the pypi page the middleware version is 0.6.1 and  supports Django 3.0 also. But from the above code snippet, it would seem that the middleware code checks only for Django version 2 to use the `is_authenticated` property instead of the `is_authenticated()` function, and could be the reason for the error. Am I correct?  Or could the error be caused by some other reason?

Comment: What version of `django-login-required-middleware` do you have installed? Can you run `pip freeze` to see? The latest version of that package does not contain that code

Comment: My bad!! I had installed `django-login-required` and not 'django-login-required-middleware`. Now the problem is solved. Thanks a ton @IainShelvington

Answer (score 1):

Update the middleware or fix if condition yourself as Django 3 routes you to else which is `is_authenticated()' like 1.11 which fails

Comment: I did the suggested workaround. But problem was something else, as I have said in my comment below that of @IainShelvington.